# VBA - Word change the concept of word(a.b is one word or two)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a question: i want to have an array of words of a WORD document, which are larger than 29 and Shorter than 40 characters. I implemented it in VBA this way:

```
Sub function()

    Dim arr(1000) As String
    counter = 0

    For Each sentence In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        For Each w In sentence.Words
            If Len(w) > 28 And Len(w) < 40 Then
                arr(counter) = w
                counter = counter + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

The Problem is that I want all words with char '_' cosidered as one word; for example: 'Adrian_link_mart' is one word and not 3: 'Adrian' and 'link' and 'mart' like it will be considered

thanks for your help, adrian

Comment: One more nested loop like `For Each w2 In Split(w, "_")` will do the job. `Split()` will return an array formed by the string `w` split by the delimiter `_`. In there you can just do your `if` and `arr(Counter)=` business on `w2`.

Comment: What's your actual question? How is the code you have not working, exactly? I think those who've responded in comments are interpreting incorrectly... FWIW you can't change how Word recognizes what a "word" is. You need to explain the logic required for your requirement. For example, is every occurrence of a `_` to be appended to the "word" before and after it? If not, when not?

Comment: Yeah, now that I'm playing around with it @CindyMeister I see that I had the problem backwards. Perhaps the solution is just to join values ending in `_` with the following value?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Probably, but let's wait until the OP provides more precise information...

Answer (score 0):

This may help.  There is a bit of a wrinkle as you will see below.

```
Option explicit

Sub test()

' Use a collection rather than an array as we don't need
' to know the size in advance
Dim word_array              As Collection
' Word doesn't actually have a  'word' object. Probably because
' that clashes with Word the application.  So instead of Word.Word
' we are using word.range which gives us all the utility we will
' need
Dim my_word_range           As Word.Range
Dim my_range                As Word.Range

    For Each my_range In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        For Each my_word_range In my_range.Words
            With my_word_range
                Do While .Next(unit:=wdCharacter) = "_"
                    ' '_' is considered to be a word  by Word so we need to
                    ' count two Word words to get to the end of the next
                    ' text word IYSWIM
                    .MoveEnd unit:=wdWord, Count:=2

                Loop

                If .Characters.Count > 28 And .Characters.Count < 40 Then
                    word_array.Add Item:=.Text

                End If

            End With

        Next

    Next

End Sub
```

If you are new to VBA then

1. Include Option explicit at the top of every module
2. In the VBA IDE go Tools.Option.Editor.Code Settings and make sure every box is ticked.
3. Learn how to use F1.  In the VBA IDE, putting the cursor on a keyword and pressing F1 will bring up the MS help page for that keyword